ImportError: cannot import name 'BPF' from 'bcc' (unknown location)
My bcc is build here:
/home/pegasus_vm/Documents/eBPFShield/bcc/build

Why I try to run python main.py -h from /home/pegasus_vm/Documents/eBPFShield/
It shows the following error:
(env) pegasus_vm@pegasusvm:~/Documents/eBPFShield$ python main.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pegasus_vm/Documents/eBPFShield/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bcc import BPF
ImportError: cannot import name 'BPF' from 'bcc' (unknown location)

I have added the bcc to the path inside ~/.bashrc like this:
bcctools=/home/pegasus_vm/Documents/eBPFShield/bcc/build/tools
bccexamples=/home/pegasus_vm/Documents/eBPFShield/bcc/build/examples
export PATH=$bcctools:$bccexamples:$PATH                 


does python3 main.py -h run as expected? Or if you are using a virtual environment, did you activate the environment first?

Check the python version first.
You may have multiple python versions installed. And the default one is python2 or not the python3.x you installed bcc packages to.
Python search packages under path lilke /usr/local/lib/python3.x/dist-packages or /lib/python3.x/dist-packages . In this way it can handle packages management for multiple python versions.  If you have multiple python3.x, check the dist-packages and see which version it is installed to.
